# Pull images from ECR using Kubelet credential provider is not working in Microk8s

Tags: amazon-ecr, microk8s

I am trying to configure a kubelet image credential provider to pull images from an ECR private registry. It looks like the 'ecr-credential-provider' gets registered but never pulls image from ECR. I am expecting that the credential provider should pull images from my private registry.

Here are the steps that I followed.

1. Create a new file `/var/snap/microk8s/common/credential-provider-config.yaml` with the following content.

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1
kind: CredentialProviderConfig
providers:
  - name: ecr-credential-provider
    apiVersion: credentialprovider.kubelet.k8s.io/v1
    matchImages:
      - "*.dkr.ecr.*.amazonaws.com"
    defaultCacheDuration: 12h
```

2. Add following arguments in file `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet`. The credential provider binary is `/usr/local/bin/ecr-credential-provider`.

```
--image-credential-provider-config=${SNAP_COMMON}/credential-provider-config.yaml
--image-credential-provider-bin-dir=/usr/local/bin/
```

3. Restart Microk8s
4. Create a Pod that uses images in my repository.